Openthread on Zephyr (Nordic nrf52840 dk)
I am trying to run openthread on a nrf52840 bord but i have no idea where to start. There are some examples, but sadly these do not run or are way to complicated to understand. Therefore I am wondering if someone could provide some sources on what the basic configurations are. So i am looking for a basic tutorial. Maybe someone can help. Would be really great.
Thanks!
I tried running the looking through the echo server and echo client on. I also tried the coprocessor but I am not even sure what it does.

Starting with the Codelab from Google is probably the easiest. This is for Nordic's NCS, which is based on Zephyr.
